# Indexing rows of each layer in a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem using NumPy which I have been working on for three hours and I can't figure it out. It's a five part problem and I figured four out of the five, but this last one I just can't figure out. Given a 3-dimensional array called "X", how would you find the index of the row with the smallest standard deviation in each layer?

So far I have this:

```
min_std_row_layer = X.std(axis = "").argmin()
```

But I don't know if that's even a good starting point.

Comment: Are you using a library? If so, which one?

Comment: I am only using NumPy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say the first dimension of X is the *layer*, second is *row*, third is *column*.

There is a very compact way to do this:

```
print(np.argmin(np.std(X, 2), 1))
```

The 2 in `np.std(X,2)` specifies that we want the standard deviations across the third dimension (0, 1, **2**). These are the **rows** in X. We will get a standard deviation for *all* the rows in *each layer*, so this will return a 2d array with shape (num_layers, num_rows).

We now need to find the index of the minimum value in the rows of each layer.

`np.argmin(np.std(X, 2) , 1)`

The **1** indicates that we want the minimum of the row in each layer.
Our final result will be a 1d array where each element is the index of the row in X with the smallest standard deviation.